How to limit/snap the rotation to certain degrees at an instance on points Geometry Nodes setup?
I want to rotate/snap objects in a Geometry Nodes collection at the Z-axis, my goal is to rotate them just to 90, 180, 270 degrees. Preferably still adjustable with a extra nodes, to leave room for small tweaks/ variations. How do I approach that?


just use a random value (integer) node from 0 to 3 and multiply by 45 degrees (pi/2) ?

sorry, meant 90 degrees of course - shame on me

You basically have several options for this.
On the one hand, you can use the math node Snap to snap the randomly generated values to specific steps:

Or, as noted by Chris in the comments, you can multiply integer values by an angle of $90°$:

Both solutions lead to the desired result. Note, however, that the distribution leads to fundamentally different results.
